# How to make text plural?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

I want the text "Max Attendee" to be plural when CurrentContacts is not equal to 1. The code below is not working:

```
Text("^[Max Attendee \(currentContacts)](inflect: true)")
```

Expected results:

```
Max Attendees 0
Max Attendee 1
Max Attendees 2
Max Attendees 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because this is not how people usually speak English, so the inflection engine behaves weirdly. See also [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/162512/183523) on ELU.SE.

When you want "Max Attendees" to come first, you should always use plural, and also add a colon in between. "Max Attendees: 1" is fine. "Max Attendee 1" is weird.

It is when the noun comes *after* the number, do we inflect. "Max 1 Attendee", "Max 2 Attendees", etc.

Compared the outputs of

```
Text("^[Max Attendees \(n)](inflect: true)")
```

and

```
Text("^[Max \(n) Attendees](inflect: true)")
```

The former results in "Attendees" for every number, and the latter results in "Max Attendee" for 1, and "Max Attendees" for everything else.

If you really want to put "Max Attendee" first and also inflect, add explicit localisation keys for the singular/plural forms in your string catalog. That is, use

```
Text("Max Attendees \(i)")
```

Right-click on the string catalog key, and click "Vary by plural". Then you can write whatever text you want in each case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Their is a very easy way to do this. o(^v^)o

You can use `Bool ? String : String` to judge is it an odd number (the number is 1).

Which `currentContacts == 1 ? "Max Attendee" : "Max Attendees"`

Example:
[image: Example picture]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(0..<6, id: \.self) { currentContacts in
        let attendeeText = currentContacts == 1 ? "Max Attendee" : "Max Attendees"
        
        Text("\(attendeeText) \(currentContacts)")
      }
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```